# making query parameter in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to return differently depending on the query parameter, how do i do that in express js

for example:

```
 app.get('/p', (req, res)=>{
     if(req.query.p = 1) res.send('hello');
     else res.send('wrong');
    });
```

if p = 1 it should send 'hello' and if p is not 1 it should send wrong

Thanks

Comment: Use `==` to compare, not `=`!

Comment: i think you are mixing up queries with slugs

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use route parameters. If that is the case you can achieve what you want to do like so:

```
app.get('/:p', (req, res) => {
if (parseInt(req.params.p) == 1) {
    res.send('hello');
}
else {
    res.send('wrong')
};
```

});